# Not able to export large Report from Web Application

Tags: asp.net, reporting

I have a web application.Reporting services are using to handle reports.I am able to display the reports in browser. But while trying to export to PDF , i am getting "time out " error in case of large sized  report.But while trying to export from the report server , then i can export.I have done in web.config as in  attached to solve this.- 
But still it is showing the same error.[image]

Answer (score 1):

With such high timeouts (3 hours) on your web.config, most likely, you're hitting your browser's timeout, most web browsers don't wait indefenitely for a server to respond, so they close the connection after a while, on some of them you can change that, so, for example, if you're using Internet Explorer, you can change the registry to enable a larger timeout by setting the

```
ReceiveTimeout
```

subkey under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

to an appropiate value (in milliseconds).

There are similar settings on other browsers, so you may want to look up the one you use, for the exact procedure.

Comment: thanks for your response. Is there any other solution. Because we are not able to change  this settings for every client.Please look on this thing that,   I am able to get the PDF report with in 20 seconds from report server.But from browser i am not able to get.

Comment: Have you confirmed that these settings let you see the report without timing out?

Comment: Will it need to execute query again for exporting or taking report from which already fetched .